# Detect referring URL hide DIV using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to use "referring URL" and when the referring website is detected, e.g., coming from example.com, then target landing page would hide `<div class="helloworld"></div>` that is displayed on the page?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {  
        if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) == "example.com"){  
                var referrer =  document.referrer;
                           $(".helloworld").hide();
            }
    });
<div class="helloworld">hidden when example.com is the referring URL</div>
```

Any help with the jquery to write this out

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` takes a string and searches for the first instance of that string inside the string in question.  The result is a numeric value of the index, -1 if not found.

So your code should be something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var referrer =  document.referrer;
    if(!referrer) return; // no referrer

    if(referrer.toLowerCase().indexOf("example.com") !== -1){  

                       $(".helloworld").hide();
        }
})
```

Comment: @IForti `!==` is a valid operator.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp